# KUP-05011 while reading External Table

Tags: oracle, external

We have a process that reads an external table of the Listener Log to gather stats.   We just upgraded to Oracle 12c, and have started receiving this message:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEFETCH callout
ORA-29400: data cartridge error
KUP-05011: Size of file listener.log in directory
/u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/db1/listener/trace has changed from 473100830 to 473101047.
```

Of course the listener.log will change......is there any way to prevent this error?

Comment: Copy the listener log to another file name, and use _that_ file.

Comment: [From the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/errmg/KUP-00552.html#GUID-436CAFD1-F65F-475B-8B3D-FC72A7983313__GUID-1A5A32D0-07B8-4547-BE2F-17BA65B1423A): "Do not modify the data files for an external table while querying the table." You may have just got lucky in your earlier version, with no data being written to the log at the moment you queried it, by chance. Working from a copy seems sensible.